# c#: HttpListener setup on https without admin rights

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use HttpListener for creating small https server listening on my custom port with self-signed certificates.

I followed some tutorials and I can create Https server by using HttpListener
But I must use admin rights for:

1. Add certificate to local computer certificates (Trusted Root &
   Personal)
2. Use "netsh http add sslcert"

I'd like to setup Https without admin rights. 
I know I can use TcpListener. With TcpListener I should only import CA certificate in my personal store. It doesn't require admin rights. 
But there is need to parse http request manually.

Is there any way to setup HttpListener without admin rights? Or use parser on tcp listener?

Answer (score 2):

You need to grant permissions to the particular URL, for example:

```
netsh http add urlacl url="http://+:4200/" user=everyone
```

please note the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-http-and-https).

Comment: But this operation requires admin rights as I mentioned before. But is there other way without admin rights?

Comment: `http add urlacl` does not require admin privileges as much as I know.

Comment: I cannot achieve this now on my system without admin rights. If I can achieve this, how can I add certificate to local computer without admin priviligies?

Comment: @BarrJ yes it does require admin: 
`> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:10166/ user=everyone

Url reservation add failed, Error: 5
The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator).`